# Slightly weaker adjective than "heavily" in "heavily used"?

Tags: adjectives

This is a very simple question, but I found it's something hard to search for on the internet. When something is used a lot, we can say **"something is heavily used"**. If it's almost abandoned, we can say **"something is barely used"**. Then if something is fairly well-used so that you can find it here and there but still not in the level of *heavily used*, what adjective should I use in this case?

Answer (score 3):

I would probably describe it as:

> Fairly well-used.

Or (perhaps a little stronger in some cases):

> Quite well-used.

Answer (score 0):

Since I did find this hard to search for, I'll include options I can think of for various levels of use.  These are not all synonyms for each other, just examples that could convey the level of usage.  Some are going to be more or less appropriate depending on the context.

**Sees a lot of use**

Well-loved, well-worn, heavily used, extensively used, used a lot/ton, used often/frequently, used all the time, it's my go-to *noun*, my *noun* of choice

**Sees some use**

Fairly well-used, sees moderate usage, sees its fair share of use, used plenty, used enough, used from time to time, used sometimes, used semi-regularly, there when I need it

**Sees almost no use**

Gathering dust, gathering cobwebs, lightly used, barely used, never used, sees no use, used sparingly, used rarely, avoided as much as possible